# python mysql connector - bandwidth consumtion

Tags: python, mysql

i have a python script  that connect to remote MYSQL(mariaDB) database and it run every 3 minutes for 1 month

so total 20 times per hour / 480 times per day   and for 1 month total **14880 times**

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
 host="remote_IP",    user="",    password="",    database="",
 auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
 autocommit=True
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

print(mydb.is_connected())


sql='INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES(123456789,123456789,"example text here....","example column here test test test")'
mycursor.execute(sql)

print(mycursor.rowcount)
```

So as i checked this example **sql variable** has **130 Byte**   but how much bandwidth is using python connection so i can calculate total Bytes * 14880

> Every Byte maters in my case coz im using 3G network and i need to
> calculate consumtion to check how much money i need to pay the mobile
> provider

Comment: I think you could use tcpdump/wireshark to evaluate the number of bytes running on the wire when python does the insert